# Install rosdep definition locally in a package

Tags: ros, python, rosdep, pip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On `Groovy` (and presumably applicable in the later distros), is there a way to define `rosdep` rules in a package locally to add/overwrite the ones defined in rosdistro [0]? I couldn't get the answer from reading [its doc](http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/).

I have a situation where I want to use `pip` for installing a depended library (python-psutil), instead of using `apt` (see [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-rqt/QkqYjMJ0dZk) for the reason if you're interested in it). And (according to [this discussion](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/789#issuecomment-17348070),) a rule that uses `pip` is recommended to be stored in a local file rather than in the public rule folder in rosdistro [0].

I've been trying to add a rule and necessary changes to [my package](https://github.com/130s/rqt_top/tree/3053ad51c5400855fa438c22953f41a4b1c49568) without success like this:

```
$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
: (skip)
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
updated cache in /home/ros_noodle/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
ros_noodle@ros_machine:~/catkin_ws/src/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_top$ rosdep install rqt_top
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rqt_top: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [psutil]
```

[0] https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep

`python-rosdep` 0.10.18-1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62756/install-rosdep-definition-locally-in-a-package/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot put a rosdep rule in a package. Rosdep is a system wide configuration.  You can add a custom source in your rosdep sources.  /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list

such as:
yaml file:///home/USER/local_custom_rosdep.yaml

You can use this for your own packages but you cannot distribute packages relying on this.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2